# Able to check if the table-cell NOT equals null, if so remove/hide button in the cell

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm wondering if it's possible to hide a button, if there's some kind information in the table-cell or the row (technician) is not equals to 'NULL'. It's kinda annoying to have a button there, when there's no use for it after 1 click.

My database (table name: assignment):

```
| ID | CustomerID | Name | Address | Technician |
```

My PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['customerButton'])){
    $ID = $_POST['assignment_id'];
    $user = $row_Users['username']; <--- // Name of the logged in user.

    mysql_query("UPDATE assignment SET technician = '$user' WHERE ID='$ID'"); <--- //Not sure what to put after 'WHERE'. 
}

?>
```

Here's a snippet of the dynamic table

```
<td><?php echo $row_Assignment['address']; ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $row_Assignment['technician']; ?>

<form action="" method="post"> 

    <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="".$row_Assignment['ID']."">                                 
    <input type="submit" name="customerButton" id="customerButton" value="Add">

</form>
</td>
```

Thanks!

Edit: The purpose of the code above is to let one of my technicians to be able to take an assignment. And when they've pressed the button, the row in the database UPDATE's and therefore there's no need to have a button in the table-cell, when the assignment is already taken.

Comment: Use `.hide()` to hide the button?

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, or a library, please show the rendered HTML, *not* the PHP script that generates that HTML.

Comment: Are you talking about the `Add` submit button? That will submit the form and reload the page. Why don't you just have the code that creates the table leave out the button if the technician has taken the assignment?

Comment: Taken in fact that it's a dynamic table? I'm not aware of that, I can possibly try it.

Comment: Note that your PHP needs to allow for what should happen if the button is clicked when it should have been hidden, because if several technicians have the page open at once two or more of them might click the button for the same row at almost the same moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a column in database for manage the button status called `is_taken`. and update this column when the technician click on the button. When the HTML is rendering check the status of `is_taken` column. Now your html will be like below:-

```
<td><?php echo $row_Assignment['address']; ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $row_Assignment['technician'];
   if($row_Assignment['is_taken']==0){ ?>
    <form action="" method="post"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="".$row_Assignment['ID']."">                                 
      <input type="submit" name="customerButton" id="customerButton" value="Add">
<?php }
  else{
         // do as you want to replacing with button
      }
?>
   </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Ooo, cleaver. I'll test it out.

Comment: @Perelan Test and let me know if its working for you.

Comment: You don't need a new database column. Just test whether the existing `Technician` column is not null (in which case you could, in addition to hiding the button, display the name of the technician currently assigned).

Comment: Yeah, I can basically do 'if($row_Assignment['technician'] == null)' ? or is it is_null($row_Assignment['technician']), I'm kinda new to PHP.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks  @nnnnn and kushal suthar. I'm wondering about one more thing. When I press the button now, the button is still there, but the database changes and if then i refresh the page it disappears. IF I press the button 2 times the button disappears. What causes this? I guess it's fine, but kinda annoying, lol.